# Bug: Erasing Tag/User Search query does not restore visibility of pagination controls

Tags: bug, tag-search, user-search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When you filter the user list you lose the pagination bar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12817/when-you-filter-the-user-list-you-lose-the-pagination-bar)

Steps to repro:

1. Go to a [Tag Search](https://stackoverflow.com/tags) or [User Search](https://stackoverflow.com/users) page (note that the pagination controls at the bottom are visible)
2. Type anything in the search box and wait for the results to load
3. Erase the search query so the search box is empty, and wait for the results to reload

Expected behaviour: pagination controls should re-appear when viewing by most popular tags in the default view.

Actual behaviour: the pagination controls remain hidden.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12817/when-you-filter-the-user-list-you-lose-the-pagination-bar

Comment: I noticed this a few days ago as well.  Very annoying to have to refresh the page, although I'd vastly prefer that the pagination controls just don't disappear at all (which seems to be `status-brokenbydesign`).

Comment: @Aaron: I'd rather have pagination all the time, but this has been declined in the past. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45338/make-the-tag-search-user-experience-better