# How to view all tags in user profile

Tags: feature-request, support, tags

When I click on my user profile on superuser.com, I can only see 50 tags whereas I'm active on 346 tags. How can I view the invisible tags?

Comment: Quasi-related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45338/make-the-tag-search-user-experience-better

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do that, but if you are interested what is your activity in a certain tag, just change it in the URL:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:userId+[tag]
```